# Android video export with MediaCodec - playback too fast

Tags: java, android, video, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to debug an app that splices together two pieces of video and exports them as one. The resulting video is much shorter and plays back too fast, even though the mp4 metadata shows it as being 25fps.

The application is a Unity app, with an external Java jar to handle the video encoding on Android. Leaving out the splicing bit, the same problem exists if we just take the loaded video and export that. So theoretically it should come out exactly the same, but it doesn't.

So, the Init function is as follows:

```
public void Init(String VideoPath, int inWidth, int inHeight) {
    // start our exporting dialog
    mExportDialog = new CustomAlertDialog();
    mExportDialog.CreateCustom("Exporting", "Exporting video\nPlease Wait",
            2);

    if (mDecodeName == "") {
        Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "getting filename: "
                + VideoFile.Instance(UnityPlayer.currentActivity)
                        .GetFileName());
        mDecodeName = VideoFile.Instance(UnityPlayer.currentActivity)
                .GetFileName();
    }

    // get the update value step for our progress bar
    // divide 1 by the total number of frames in the original video.
    // Multiply it by 0.85f
    mFrameProgressStep = (1.0f / (VideoFile.Instance(
            UnityPlayer.currentActivity).GetDuration() * 25.0f * 0.85f));

    // before disposing of our video get the current point of the video
    // we're at
    mCurrentSeekPoint = VideoFile.Instance(UnityPlayer.currentActivity)
            .GetCurrentTime();

    // also get the video URI so we can reinitialise the video player
    // afterwards
    mVideoURI = VideoFile.Instance(UnityPlayer.currentActivity)
            .GetVideoURI();

    // Dispose
    VideoFile.Instance(UnityPlayer.currentActivity).Dispose();

    mVideoName = VideoPath;

    // create the video file output stream at the video path supplied
    try {
        mFileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/"
                        + mVideoName + ".h264"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Unable to open video file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mWidth = inWidth;
    mHeight = inHeight;

    mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");

    // Find a code that supports the mime type
    int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
    MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs && codecInfo == null; i++) {
        MediaCodecInfo info = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
        if (!info.isEncoder()) {
            continue;
        }
        String[] types = info.getSupportedTypes();
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < types.length && !found; j++) {
            if (types[j].equals("video/avc"))
                found = true;
        }
        if (!found)
            continue;
        codecInfo = info;
    }
    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Found " + codecInfo.getName() + " supporting " + "video/avc");

    // Find a color profile that the codec supports
    mColourFormat = 0;
    MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType("video/avc");
    for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length && mColourFormat == 0; i++) {
        int format = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
        switch (format) {
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
            mColourFormat = format;
            break;
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar:
            mColourFormat = format;
            break;
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar:
            mColourFormat = format;
            break;
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
            mColourFormat = format;
            break;
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
            mColourFormat = format;
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Skipping unsupported color format " + format);
            break;
        }
    }

    // setup the media format
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", mWidth, mHeight);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4000000);
    // set the frame rate to 25FPS
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, mColourFormat);
    // add a key frame every second
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);

    MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();

    // configure the media codec as an encoder, we don't have an input
    // surface and we're not encrypting the video
    mMediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

    // start the encoder
    mMediaCodec.start();

    mExportDialog.SetProgress(5);
}
```

Then the encode function is as follows:

```
public void Encode() {
    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Encode Orig Video: " + mDecodeName);

    mExportDialog.SetProgress(15);

    float currentProgress = 15.0f;

    int VIDEO_FPS = 25;

    MediaCodec decoder = null;

    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "creating media extractor");
    MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
    try {
        extractor.setDataSource(mDecodeName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // create our output surface ready for our decoder to render on
    mOutputSurface = new CodecOutputSurface(mWidth, mHeight);

    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "getting track count");
    int numTracks = extractor.getTrackCount();
    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "track count is: " + numTracks);

    for (int i = 0; i < numTracks; ++i) {
        MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);

        if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
            Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Found Correct track");
            extractor.selectTrack(i);
            // Decoder
            decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);

            // configure our decoder to use the mOutputSurface
            decoder.configure(format, mOutputSurface.getSurface(), null, 0);

            break;
        }
    }

    if (decoder == null) {
        Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find video info");
        return;
    } else
        Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Decoder is Fine");

    // Start Decoder
    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Start Decoder");
    decoder.start();

    // Get the average duration of a frame
    long averageDuration = Math.round((1.0f / 25.0f) * 1000000.0f);

    // Variables
    //boolean specialFrame = false;
    float addition = 0;
    long timeStamp = 0;

    // Byte Buffer
    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Assigning memory for buffer");
    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();

    // Gets filled with buffer Meta Data
    BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();

    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Starting read Loop. Analysis List size: "
            + analysisPoints.size());

    // create a variable for our presentation stamp and the one from the
    // last frame
    long presentationTimeUs = 0;
    long prevPresentationTimeUs = 0;

    int outIndex = -1;

    while (true) {
        int sampleSize = 0;

        int trackIndex = extractor.getSampleTrackIndex();
        presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();

        // Get Decoder Index
        int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);

        if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
            // free buffer
            inputBuffers[inputBufIndex].clear();

            // if(VERBOSE) Log.v(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "adding: " +
            // presentationTimeUs + " - " + prevPresentationTimeUs +
            // "to timestamp");
            // Add the new time to time stamp
            // timeStamp += (presentationTimeUs - prevPresentationTimeUs);
            timeStamp = (presentationTimeUs);

            if ((sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(
                    inputBuffers[inputBufIndex], 0)) < 0)
                break;

            // inputBuffers[inputBufIndex].put(readData);

            // Decoding

                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, sampleSize,
                        presentationTimeUs, 0);
            while(true){
                // Get Outputbuffer Index
                outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);

                // create a flag so we only render the image when we have data
                // on the dequeued output buffer
                boolean doRender = true;// (info.size != 0);

                if(outIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER){
                    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,"outIndex == INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER");
                    break;
                }
                else if (outIndex >= 0) {
                    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,"outIndex >= 0");
                    // Release buffer
                    decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, doRender);

                    // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                    // "extractor Advance! bufferIndex: " + inputBufIndex);
                    extractor.advance();

                    // increment current progress
                    currentProgress += mFrameProgressStep;
                    // set the export bar value
                    mExportDialog.SetProgress(Math.round(currentProgress));


                if (analysisPoints.size() > 0
                        && (presentationTimeUs / 100000) == analysisPoints.get(0).startTime) {
                    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Found Special frame");

/*                  // addition = analysisPoints.get(0).duration;

                    // Clock that we're inserting a special frame
                    specialFrame = true;
                }

                if (specialFrame) {
*/
                    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Encoding Special frame"
                            + " at time: " + timeStamp);

                    boolean isCutPaste = (analysisPoints.get(0).copyPastes.size() > 0);

                    int textureID[] = { -1, -1 };

                    // create a texture from the analysispoint's frame data
                    CreateTexture(textureID);

                    //The Index we're icnrementing to get copy paste Index
                    int positionIndex = 0;
                    float[] position = {-1.0f,-1.0f};

                    int numberFrames = VIDEO_FPS * (int) analysisPoints.get(0).duration;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberFrames; i++) 
                    {
                        //Draw main Analysis image
                        mOutputSurface.drawAnalysisImage(textureID[0], true);

                        if (isCutPaste) 
                        {
                            int length = analysisPoints.get(0).copyPastes.size();                           
                            for (int copyPasteCounter = 0; copyPasteCounter < length; ++copyPasteCounter) 
                            {
                                // Get the Copy and Paste item
                                CopyPasteData copyPasteData = analysisPoints.get(0).copyPastes.get(copyPasteCounter);

                                float[] vertices = {
                                        // X, Y, Z, U, V
                                        -.10f, -.10f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
                                         .10f, -.10f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
                                        -.10f,  .10f, 0, 0.f, 1.f, 
                                         .10f,  .10f, 0, 1.f, 1.f, };

                                // Create Float buffer
                                ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
                                vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // use the device hardware's native byte order
                                FloatBuffer fb = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
                                fb.put(vertices); // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
                                fb.position(0); // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
                                if(positionIndex < copyPasteData.Positions.length)
                                    position[0] = copyPasteData.Positions[positionIndex++];
                                if(positionIndex < copyPasteData.Positions.length)
                                    position[1] = copyPasteData.Positions[positionIndex++];

                                //Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,"mOutputSurface.drawCutPasteImage Position x: " + position[0] + " y: " + position[1]);
                                mOutputSurface.drawCutPasteImage(textureID[1], position, fb, true);
                            }
                        }

                        //render Image to buffer
                        ByteBuffer decodedBuffer = mOutputSurface.renderToBuffer();

                        byte[] newArray = new byte[decodedBuffer.remaining()];
                        //reqind Array
                        decodedBuffer.rewind();
                        decodedBuffer.get(newArray);

                        // the image data should in the size of YUV which is a 3byte
                        // variable
                        byte[] imageData = new byte[(mWidth * mHeight * 3) / 2];

                        covertToYUV(imageData, newArray, mWidth, mHeight);

                        timeStamp += averageDuration;

                        // Perform Encoding
                        EncodeFrame(imageData, timeStamp + (long) addition);
                    }

                    // update the addition
                    addition += analysisPoints.get(0).duration;

                    //specialFrame = false;

                    // remove used frame data
                    analysisPoints.get(0).byteBuffer.clear();
                    analysisPoints.remove(0);
                    GLES20.glDeleteTextures(textureID.length, textureID, 0);
                } else {
                    // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                    // "Encoding Standard frame! SampleSize: " + sampleSize +
                    // " at time: " + timeStamp);

                    // Check Outputbuffer Index is valid and we have an image to
                    // render
                    //if (outIndex >= 0 && doRender) {
                        // if(VERBOSE) Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                        // "Awaiting new image");
                        mOutputSurface.awaitNewImage();

                        // if(VERBOSE) Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                        // "Draw new image");
                        mOutputSurface.drawImage(false);

                        // if(VERBOSE) Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                        // "Render to buffer");
                        // get the buffer from the outputSurface
                        ByteBuffer decodedBuffer = mOutputSurface
                                .renderToBuffer();

                        // Convert to byte array
                        byte[] newArray = new byte[decodedBuffer.remaining()];
                        decodedBuffer.rewind();
                        decodedBuffer.get(newArray);

                        // the image data should in the size of YUV which is a
                        // 3byte variable
                        byte[] imageData = new byte[(mWidth * mHeight * 3) / 2];

                        // if(VERBOSE) Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                        // "Encoding RGBA to YUV");
                        covertToYUV(imageData, newArray, mWidth, mHeight);

                        // if(VERBOSE) Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                        // "Perfom encode");
                        // Perform Encoding
                        EncodeFrame(imageData, timeStamp + (long) addition);
                    //} 

                    /*else {
                        switch (outIndex) {
                        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                            Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                                    "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                            outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                            Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                                    "New output buffer size = "
                                            + outputBuffers.length);
                            break;
                        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                            Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                                    "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());
                            break;
                        case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                            Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                                    "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out! Index: "
                                            + outIndex);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
                                    "Found output buffer Index! " + outIndex);
                            break;
                        }
                    }*/

                }
            }
            else{
                Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,"outIndex: "+outIndex);
            }
        }
        }

        // update the previous presentation stamp here
        prevPresentationTimeUs = presentationTimeUs;

        // Log
        //Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Looping");
    }

    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Finished Encoding");

    extractor.release();
    extractor = null;

    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Time to hint at some garbage collection");
    System.gc();

    UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            mExportDialog.SetProgress(100);
        }
    });
}
```

Looking at the PresentationTime of the source video from extractor.getSampleTime(), I can see there is a time of 0.16s between frames. For a video at 25fps would I not expect to see 0.04s between frames?  I tried modifying the presentation time but that made no difference.

The problem appears to be in the encode function, rather than the final MUX to mp4, as the raw H264 file shows the same issue, i.e. plays back too fast.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with the code above?

EDIT: added the EncodeFrame function code:

```
void EncodeFrame(byte[] data, long inPTS) {
    // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Getiing input/output buffers");
    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

    // get the input buffer index to use
    int inBuffIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);

    // if we have an invalid buffer index then there's something wrong
    if (inBuffIndex < 0) {
        Log.e(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "No input buffer available");
        return;
    }

    // Log
    // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Clearing input buffer");
    // put our frame data into the the input buffer we've been given
    inputBuffers[inBuffIndex].clear();

    // Log
    // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Putting data of size: " + data.length +
    // " into buffer, index: " + inBuffIndex + " and size:" +
    // inputBuffers[inBuffIndex].limit());
    // Insert the Data into the buffer
    inputBuffers[inBuffIndex].put(data);

    // Log
    // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Queuing input data");
    // queue the inputbuffer
    mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inBuffIndex, 0, data.length, inPTS, 0);

    // For testing increase the pts by 1/FPS * 1,000,000 to convert the
    // value into microseconds
    // mCurrentPts += Math.round((1.0f/25.0f)*1000000.0f);

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo buffInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int outBuffIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(buffInfo, 0);

    // use a do while loop as we need to check if the output buffers have
    // changed
    do {
        // if we have a valid buffer index
        if (outBuffIndex >= 0) {
            // get the data from our output buffer
            // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG,
            // "Getting data from buffer, with index: "+ outBuffIndex
            // +" and size:" + outputBuffers[outBuffIndex].limit());
            byte[] outData = new byte[buffInfo.size];
            outputBuffers[outBuffIndex].get(outData);

            try {
                // if we have an offset write to the file using the offset
                if (buffInfo.offset != 0) {
                    Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Writing data with offset");
                    mFileStream.write(outData, buffInfo.offset,
                            outData.length);
                } else {
                    // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Writing data");
                    mFileStream.write(outData);
                }

                mFileStream.flush();

                // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Releasing output Buffer");
                // release the output buffer
                mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outBuffIndex, false);

                // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Getting next output index");
                // check if there's another buffer that has an output for us
                outBuffIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(buffInfo, 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Error writing to output file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // if the buffer index isn't valid, check if it means the output
        // buffers have changed
        else if (outBuffIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            // Log.d(UnityAppPlayer.TAG, "Output buffers have changed");
            // get the output buffers again
            outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        }
    } while (outBuffIndex >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The presentation time stamps for each frame are in the muxed .mp4 file. They do not exist in the H.264 file. The MediaCodec just forwards the timestamp along with the frame to maintain the association; this is important for codecs that can produce frames out of order.

The code you need to look at is the part that calls [`MediaMuxer#writeSampleData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html#writeSampleData(int,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo)), in particular the value of the presentation times in the `BufferInfo` object.  Make sure you're generating PTS values for the source frames, and that the PTS associated with each frame submitted to the encoder is obtained with the encoded frame and forwarded to the MediaMuxer.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm on the right track now I think. I was using the Google mp4Parser to create an MP4 from the raw H264 stream before, now I'm trying to use the MediaMuxer. One problem though - when I try to set the BufferInfo.presentationTimeUs I get the following error from MPEG4Writer in LogCat: "Condition timestampUs >= 011 failed for Video track". Any idea what this means? I've been googling for the error message, but can't find anything useful.

Comment: Actually, looking into this a bit further, I'm only getting 96 frames out of 250 for a 10s video at 25fps. All the other frames are timing out with bufferIndex returning -1.

Comment: Make sure your timestamps are increasing and have reasonable values (time in microseconds). Which call is timing out? Bear in mind that you can't generally supply one frame and expect one frame to come out of MediaCodec; you may have to add several then wait (see the "basic usage" pattern on http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/). Your posted code appears to have a dequeueOutputBuffer() call with a 10ms timeout that only tries once.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I'm really struggling here though. I tried wrapping the dequeuOutputBuffer in a while loop, and although the output look like it's working better, the output video is all garbled. can you see anything else wrong with the above code? I've updated it to show what I have now.

Comment: Garbled how? What frame format is the encoder expecting? (You can't dictate the input format to the encoder -- you have to query what it wants and rewrite the frame as needed. See e.g. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest .)